# What distribution is $a e^{-bx^2}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, terminology

I am trying to find the name of the following distribution, with support $x>0$:

$$f(x)=a e^{-bx^2}$$

Any idea?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: note the condition on the support. I believe this is a $\chi$ distribution with one degree of freedom instead.

Comment: @carmichael561 Ah, yes, didn't see that. The absolute value of a normal variate will do. Same as a $\chi_1$ of course.